# Не сохраняется изображение в отдельную таблицу

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity

Ниже в коде не срабатывает

```
MC.Photos.Add(image);
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEvent(Event newEvent, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            var image = new Photo()
            {
                ImageMimeType = file.ContentType,
                ImageData = new byte[file.ContentLength]
            };

            file.InputStream.Read(image.ImageData, 0, file.ContentLength);
            MC.Photos.Add(image);
        }
        newEvent.PhotoId = newEvent.EventId+1;
        MC.Events.Add(newEvent);
        MC.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Redirect("Index");     
}
```

Сущность Photo

```
public class Photo
{
    [Key]
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
}
```

Почему не сохраняет вторую таблицу?
Может проблема в форме?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEvent", "Admin"))
{       
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Название мероприятия</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.NameOfEvent)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Дата мероприятия</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.DateOfEvent)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Описание</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Description)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Количество билетов</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.CountOfTickets)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Цена билетов</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.CostOfTicket)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Изображение</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
}
```

Comment: Отлаживайте, пишите логи. А пока похоже, что проблема за пределами показанного кода.

Comment: Добавил код формы, которая отправляет изображение и другие данные. С другими данными все в порядке, сохраняются

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что я не указал в параметрах формы

```
FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }
```